# I keep getting a msg saying that OSX can't run a Java app because I don't have java installed

Tags: macos, java

I keep getting a msg saying that OSX can't run a Java app because I don't have java installed.  How do I find out what app it is trying to run? This began happening after updating to Yosemite, so it might be related here:  http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1803947&page=3

Trying to decide if I fix java or uninstall the app that keeps failing.

Answer (score 1):

OSX Yosemite doesn't come with Java installed and ifg you had it before it'll be removed. You have two possible options:

**Install [Apple Java (1.6) for OSX](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572)**

This version of Java is older than the latest available from Oracle but many Java apps running on OSX require this version. For example many of the Jetbrains IDEs recommend using this version of the

**Install [Oracle Java for OSX](https://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp)**

This is a much newer and more regularly updated version of Java howvever it has suffered reliability and security issues. One of the reasons for Apple no longer bundling Java with the OS is due to these problems.

So in summary you could install the older, more stable Java or the newer less stable version. It entirely depends on the needs you and the application have.

**Further Reading**

- [Get Java OSX on Yosemite](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/21/get-java-os-x-yosemite/) - recommends Apple Java
- [Java advice from Oracle](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml) - recommends Oracle Java